# Using different images for checkboxes in CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have seen questions asking how to replace the checkbox with an image which have been answered, but I am having a separate issue.
I am trying to make a form with multiple check boxes, each with a different image to be used as the button by the user. Every time I try to have 2 different images, one won't show, and only one button will work. Any help is appreciated!

Here's my code:

```css
     .services_form input[type="checkbox"]{
     display:none;
     }


     .services_form input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
     {
       background-color: #bdc3c7;
       background-size: 100%;
       height: 250px;
       width: 250px;
          opacity: 0.5;
       display:inline-block;
       padding: 0 0 0 0px;
     }


     .services_form input[type=checkbox] + label
     {
       background-size: 100%;
       height: 250px;
       width: 250px;
       display:block;
       float: left;
       padding: 0 0 0 0px;
       cursor: pointer;
     }

    #accomButton{
      background: url("button1.png") no-repeat;
    }

    #fooBar{
         background-image: url("button2.png");
    }

    .button {
      float: left;
      width: 35%;
      height: 35%;
      border-radius: 15%;
      margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
    }
```

```html
    <form class="services_form">
        <div class="accomButton">
        <input type="checkbox" id="accomButton"></input>
        <label for="accomButton" id="accomLabel"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
        <input type="checkbox" id="foo"></input>
        <label for"foo" id="fooBar"></label>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: wrong syntax in "<label for"foo" id="fooBar"></label>" - should be "<label for="foo" id="fooBar"></label>"

Comment: What a silly mistake, well spotted. Thank you! That fixed the other button being unresponsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `background: url("button1.png") no-repeat;` not in `#accomButton` but in `#accomLabel` as you do for `#fooBar`.